# Remote controls of audio player are not visible in IOS 11 lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer

I have a custom class which plays an audio with AVPlayer. In the method of this class have added play, pause, previous and next track commands to MPRemoteCommandCenter instance like so:

```
let mediaPlayerCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    mediaPlayerCommandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playRemoteHandler(_:))) // .. and so on
```

I have added also MPNowPlayingInfoCenter details.
"Background mode" is turned on in the "Capabilities" section of project settings and app plays audio in background normally.

---

In the application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method AVAudioSession category selected and activated also:

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    application.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents() // in the documentation noticed that it is not necessary if we are using MPRemoteCommandCenter but anyways I tried it also
```

---

After all these codes, remote controls are visible neither in lock screen nor contol center. But audio plays normally in the background.

Comment: Have you tried adding `nowPlayingInfo` on `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()`? It's a dictionary with constants as keys, such as `MPMediaItemPropertyArtist`, `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle`, and so on

Comment: @Frederik, Yes. As I noticed, added all of them. But no result

Comment: Are you running on simulator or real device? Or is it both?

Comment: @Frederik I'm running it on simulator

Comment: I did a project in the fall on something similar - we had some problems regarding the simulator, however, I don't recall if it was the playback in the background or the playback controls. Can you try when setting the category and use `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [])`, or maybe adding the playback rate to the `nowPlayingInfo` using `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` and setting the value of `NSNumber(value: 1.0)` (if playing)

Comment: @Frederik, tried but no result :/

Comment: Then I think you might need to test on a real device. I just ran my sample project on a simulator where it plays in the background, but control center is blank. On real device it works fine.

Comment: Yes, the last variant was to test on real IOS device. And you're right, it works very well on it. It seems something is wrong in simulator. @Frederik, thank you for your advices.

Comment: I have noticed that if you are plugged into the debugger, the controls don't show up. As soon as I unplug from USB and restart the app the controls all work.